# wso2 : Access to package?

Tags: wso2, jmx, mbeans

**How can i access to a package?**

I need to use this package in my class for using Mbean.

```
org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.service
```

where can i download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the carbon kernel module.You can find the libraries in any of wso2 products.

eg: wso2AS.

Check the home\repository\components\plugins folder

Comment: Thank you dear Ratha for quick response. i want to use jmx(mbean) for get to attribute and method of Application Server. i should to use proxy for access to attribute and method is it true? can u help me in this scenario please?

Comment: what attributes you are trying to get?..You can start the server and connect via jconsole and get all relevant mbean data there

Comment: I asked this issue in a new question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997327/wso2-statisticsclient link. please refer to it and help me.thank you.

Comment: i want to invoke avgresponsetime method of StatisticsAdmin type for a specific service in code. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can download org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.service dependency jars from 
http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/wso2/carbon/org.wso2.carbon.server.admin/

Please download jar based on required dependency version